# How to parse Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)

Tags: time, go

I'm trying to parse a time value (received via email) but I can't find what layout I should use.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    layout := "Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST-07:00)"
    data := "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

[Check](http://play.golang.org/p/IUXSEG9Rr_)

`panic: parsing time "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)" as "Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST-07:00)": cannot parse ":00)" as "-07:00"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the **Important note!** section to get a full picture as the last part including `GMT` is not what it seems (that is, it is not the zone abbreviation).

---

Your input time string is not parsable as-is with the `time` package because in the last part `(GMT+08:00)` the zone abbreviation and the zone offset are not separated with any extra characters. And since the zone abbreviation is not limited to 3 characters, the `"+08"` is also treated as part of the zone abbreviation, which will only leave the rest `":00)"` to match the zone offset `"-07:00"` hence the error message:

```
cannot parse ":00)" as "-07:00"
```

Possible workaround:

Simply cut off the extra zone offset as it is redundant (duplicate because zone offset is included twice):

```
func Parse(s string) (time.Time, error) {
    if len(s) < 7 {
        return time.Time{}, errors.New("Too short!")
    }
    s = s[:len(s)-7]
    layout := "Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST"
    return time.Parse(layout, s)
}
```

And using it:

```
data := "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)"
t, err := Parse(data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/W60xqB69qW).

#### Important note!

Although logically analyzing your input time string:

```
Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)
```

The last part `"(GMT+08:00)"` **does not denote the zone abbreviation** (GMT is not +0800 but +0000)! It is just a helper text to the reader explaining that the `+0800` is a zone offset to be added to the `GMT` timezone, so most likely it will always be `GMT` but not because the time is specified in the GMT timezone but because it explains that the zone offset means an offset to be added to the GMT time. And as such, it is not part of the time specification and should not be parsed.

So instead cut off all the last part and parse it like this:

```
func Parse(s string) (time.Time, error) {
    if len(s) < 12 {
        return time.Time{}, errors.New("Too short!")
    }
    s = s[:len(s)-12]
    layout := "Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700"
    return time.Parse(layout, s)
}
```

Also note that if this is really the case (that it is not the zone abbreviation but it will always be `"GMT"`), you can parse the input string without truncating it by changing your layout to include the static text `"GMT"` instead of the zone abbreviation specifier `"MST"`:

```
layout := "Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (GMT-07:00)"
data := "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT+08:00)"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Having a space between MST and - solves the panic.

```
layout := "Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST -07:00)"
data := "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800 (GMT +08:00)"
```

This works, however it does not really solve your problem.

Why not trimming the redundant timezone part? You already have +0800 defined.

```
layout := "Mon, _2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700"
data := "Mon, 5 Oct 2015 00:24:08 +0800"
```

Comment: How to trim it? I mean without to break other layouts.

Comment: The space doesn't seem to fix the issue. Am I wrong? http://play.golang.org/p/baYxSuFdse

Comment: @AnthonyHunt Having a space between MST and - (for both the layout and the data) fixes the issue. Hence my comment that it does not solve your problem :)

Comment: @AnthonyHunt My guess is that there is a problem with the golang time parser, because the layout looks correct. That's why I said you should simply cut off the (MST -07:00)/(GMT +08:00) that are redundant.

Comment: that, that's the case. There seems to be an issue on github though it was closed due backward compat.